# Polymer iron-list iterates, but not printing

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer, components, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to use an iron-list in Polymer to display an array of object as a list. Inside the polymer function, I have ...

```
ready: function() {
    this.list = [{title: 'Thing 1'}, {title: 'Thing 2'}, {title: 'Thing 3'}];
}
```

and in the template, I have ...

```
<iron-list items="[[ list ]]" as="l">
    <template>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="" on-tap="">
                <span>[[ l.title ]]</span>
                <paper-checkbox class="right"></paper-checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</iron-list>
```

I imported "iron-list.html" into the file.

What I'm seeing, is that the iron-list creates 3 templates (rightly so), but it doesn't print out the strings (the titles). This should've been simple but I'm lost here. Anyone has any idea why it doesn't print out?

**EDIT:** One important thing I left out is that this element started out with `display: none` and then toggled to show later on.

Comment: Your code looks fine, double check how you import the `iron-list.html`.

Comment: Yup, it's there. The dev tool confirms that `iron-list.html` was successfully requested.

Comment: In dev tool you should be able to inspect the text in each template right? What does it say?

Comment: All the divs and spans are there but there is no text inside the span.

Comment: This (http://plnkr.co/edit/0T2aHaLwmumTVyX9FKot?p=preview) is all your code and it works fine...

Comment: Hmm.. Yeah. It seems to always work in an example but not in the code itself :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89628/discussion-between-vleong-and-justin-xl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list), it says

> iron-list lays out the items when it recives a notification via the
>   resize event. This event is fired by any element that implements
>   IronResizableBehavior.
>
> By default, elements such as iron-pages, paper-tabs or paper-dialog
>   will trigger this event automatically. If you hide the list manually
>   (e.g. you use display: none) you might want to implement
>   IronResizableBehavior or fire this event manually right after the list
>   became visible again. e.g.

So you will need to manually call

```
document.querySelector('iron-list').fire('resize');
```

after the list is shown.

---

Also, even if you didn't hide/show the list, your code still wouldn't work 'cause you assigned the value to the `list` a bit too early.

The reason is that inside `iron-list`, the function that does the rendering `_render` will only do the job when `this._isVisible` is `true`. And `this._isVisible` is based on the sizing (`offsetWidth` & `offsetHeight`) of the `iron-list` itself.

So instead, try assigning the value inside the `attached` handler, with a little delay when needed -

```
attached: function () {
    this.async(function () {
        this.list = [{ title: 'Thing 1' }, { title: 'Thing 2' }, { title: 'Thing 3' }];
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: IINM, the event is now 'iron-resize'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you did not declare an explicit size for your iron-list element.

From the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list):

> **Important**: iron-list must ether be explicitly sized, or delegate scrolling to an explicitly sized parent. By "explicitly sized", we mean it either has an explicit CSS height property set via a class or inline style, or else is sized by other layout means (e.g. the flex or fit classes).

Comment: I defined `height: 500px` and the element inspector confirms that it's applied to `<iron-list>`.